# How to compute an injective/surjective map with minimum weight?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, implementation

We are given an `m x n` matrix `w` which represents the edge weights in a complete bipartite graph `K_m,n`. **We wish to find a map `{1,...,m} -> {1,...,n}` with minimal weight, which is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) or [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).** Choosing a map is equivalent to, for every vertex `v` in `{1,...,m}`, choosing **exactly one** edge incident to `v`.

---

Let `m<=n`. An *injective* function with minimal weight can be found by searching for the perfect matching with minimal weight. In Python, this is implemented in `scipy`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy, scipy.optimize
w=np.random.rand(5,10)
print(scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment(w))
```

---

Let `m>=n`. How can a *surjective* function with minimal weight be found? I'm looking for a concrete implementation in Python.

Comment: Are all edge weights nonnegative? If so, [this post may help](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/reducing-a-minimum-cost-edge-cover-problem-to-minimum-cost-weighted-bipartie-per); as this is a minimum weight edge cover problem

Comment: @kcsquared Isn't it true, that an edge cover can have edges that are incident on the domain set of m vertices? That would mean we don't have a map but rather a multimap.

Comment: That's true. How large are m and n, and are weights nonnegative? It may be possible to convert this to an integer linear program (with exponential runtime)

Comment: @kcsquared m and n are 10^4 or larger. The weights can be assumed to be >=0. Btw, I'm also interested in the case where `w` is a sparse matrix (then, for the injective part, we use `scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching(w)`).

Comment: I would recommend that the computer science stackexchange would be much more likely to offer help on this problem. There's no function in scipy.optimize for your question, and an expert in graph theory is more likely to know if this is an open problem or proven to be NP-hard.

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you, I will pose this question there. BTW, what about the following approach: First find the cheapest injective map `[m] <- [n]` via the transposed matrix `I=scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment(w.T)[1]`. This represents the cheapest _surjective partial_ map `[m] -> [n]`. Then for all remaining unmatched vertices, we determine the cheapest map `[m]\I -> [n]`. Is the resulting surjective map the cheapest?

Comment: That's a good approximation, but it's not always cheapest (the exact approximation ratio is not clear to me). Consider `[[3 5 6], [4 3 8], [8 2 3], [8 5 5]]` which has 4 rows and 3 columns. The first 3 rows have a min-cost assignment of 9, e.g. columns `0,1,2`. This extends to a min-cost full map of 14 by adding an element of the final row. However columns `0,1,1,2` give a min-cost full map of 13. Also, no min-cost assignment of the first 3 rows can be extended to a min-cost map of all 4. To use your strategy, you'd also need to iterate over all `m choose n` ways to pick the first n rows.

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: @Stef I have not.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: It turns out I might have misunderstood your question.*

### From injective to surjective

If `m > n`, and you already have an algorithm that handles the case `m <= n`, then swap the two components. Your algorithm will give you an injective function from the second component to the first. Take the inverse of that function; it will be a surjective function from a subset of the first component to the second component.

### Using `networkx`

What you are looking for is a maximum-cardinality matching in a bipartite graph.

The python library `networkx` contains several functions for that. Standard problems are "maximum-cardinality matching" and "maximum-weight matching"; I'd be surprised if there were a function to solve your "minimum-weight maximum-cardinality matching" problem directly.

However; it looks to me as if your problem was equivalent to finding a maximum-weight matching in the weighted graph obtained by replacing every weight `w` by `W-w`, where `W` is some very large value (for instance, three times the maximum weight in the original graph).

By including this large value `W` in the weight of every edge, you're forcing the maximum-weight matching to be a maximum-cardinality matching. And by including the negative value `-w`, you're asking the algorithm to find edges with the smallest possible original weight in the original graph.

- [Documentation: `networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html)

Comment: After rereading the post, I suspect that the statement 'Choosing a map is equivalent to, for every vertex v in {1,...,m}, choosing exactly one edge incident to v' implies that OP wants to avoid selecting only a subset of the m vertices

Comment: @kcsquare oooooooooooooooh I see

Comment: If understood correctly, you are addressing the 'injective' part of my post, but that I already solved. The problem I have is with the 'surjective' part.

Comment: @Leo If m > n, and you already have an algorithm that handles the case m <= n, then swap the two components. Your algorithm will give you an injective function from the second component to the first. Take the inverse of that function; it will be a surjective function from a subset of the first component to the second component. Then complete this partial surjective function into a surjective function by adding, for every unused vertex in the first component, its highest-weight edge. I don't know whether the result has maximum weight, but it should be a good approximation at least?

Comment: It is a good approximation, but not necessarily minimal, see comments below my original question.